# "to enable you to see" or "to enable you see"

Tags: american-english

"*to enable you to see the...*"
"*to enable you see the...*"

Is one more correct than the other? The first sounds more natural to me, but I can find references for both usages.

Comment: The first is correct.  This question is off-topic for this site.  It might go better on English Language Learners.

Comment: Where do you find references for the second?

Comment: Sorry! How is it off-topic?

Thanks Edwin, didn't find that one.

https://www.google.co.il/search?q="to+enable+you+see"

Comment: @Uri This site assumes that you have a basic understanding of English and how it's prepositions, gerunds and infinitives work, etc.  This is a basic reference question that might be welcomed on English Language Learners, but only with some research behind it.

Comment: @ David M Unfortunate typo, given the context.

Comment: @DavidM: This site assumes nothing of the sort. This site is for giving opinions on grammar, and most of the answers show little basic understanding of how English grammar works. I frankly don't see any difference between the sites, except they spread out the opinions.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes. I have to figure out how to disable select bits of Autocorrect that are making me look foolish. *Its it's* seems to throw it into a tizzy.  I've spent an inordinate amount of time fixing incorrectly inserted apostrophes.